# Complex search function SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a search function using multiple check boxes. The problem is, my client randomly asks for a list with different categories. For example, he would ask to have a list of employees with dependents, or sometimes a list of employees that are over 30 years old, or sometimes both. The list goes on, the point is he can ask me a list with any category. I would like to know how can I achieve this using check boxes, and sql commands? Thank you in advance. Sorry for my poor english btw.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to check [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a certain statement to each different checkbox, and using a form to POST each individual box. Additionally, If all queries run in the same table, you can affix a fixed statement and assign the values dynamically. The code below is a short example of how it can be done.

`$checkbox = "Name,Age"
$checkbox2 = "category2"
$query ="SELECT".$checkbox ."FROM TableName WHERE Category=".$checkbox2;`

which will give out the final statement as 
`"$query = SELECT Name,Age FROM TableName WHERE Category=category2`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are asking about how to build your where-statement out of the input from the checkboxes.

If you have a form like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test3">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

You can build a query like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $queryParams = array();
    if(isset($_POST['test'])){
        $queryParams[] = 'column1 = "test"';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['test2'])){
        $queryParams[] = 'column2 = "test2"';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['test3'])){
        $queryParams[] = 'column3 = "test3"';
    }
    $where = (count($queryParams) > 0) ? 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $queryParams) : '';
    $query = 'SELECT column FROM table ' . $where;
    echo $query;
}
```

results in:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column1 = "test" AND column2 = "test2"
```

Comment: A fine answer, but I think it's contrary to the spirit of SO to make such extensive assumptions.

Comment: @strawberry, could you be so kind as to help me with my problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you provide a small example of what you are trying to do?